# Existence of orientation-reversing automorphisms

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a connected orientable manifold (I don't really care about which category of manifolds we should work in). Since I read that there are nice manidolds without orientation-reversing automorphisms (e.g. $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ for even $n$), I'm looking for an answer to the following question:

What topological conditions ensure that $M$ admits an orientation-reversing automorphism (homeomorphism, diffeomorphism,...)?

Comment: Some obstructions: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21781/oriention-reversing-diffeomorphisms-of-a-manifold

Comment: A relevant thesis: http://bib.math.uni-bonn.de/downloads/bms/BMS-392.pdf